# key-value is not being read as expected

Tags: latex3, l3keys

I'm trying to write some code that allows me to reveal in stages the content of a pre-existing file (a `pspicture` showing a geometric construction).  I'm trying to write this using LaTeX3.  I've got some working code, but I don't like how I'm implementing it.  Currently, the working version is a hobbled together collection of commands.  I want to streamline this using `l3keys`.  However, I'm getting stuck.

> What's working:

Here's what I've got that's working.  There are three files:

File in which I define the `expl3` interface:  this is put in a file called **stages.tex**

```
%% defining stages
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N    \ace_reveal_tl
\tl_gset:Nn  \ace_reveal_tl {REVEAL}
\tl_new:N    \ace_conceal_tl
\tl_gset:Nn  \ace_conceal_tl {CONCEAL}

\NewDocumentCommand{\revealstage}{ m }{
        \tl_gset:cV { ace__reveal__ #1 __stage__new } \ace_reveal_tl
    }
\NewDocumentCommand{\burystage}{ m }{
        \tl_gset:cV { ace__reveal__ #1 __stage__new } \ace_conceal_tl
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\testforstage}{ m m m }{
            \tl_if_eq:cNTF { ace__reveal__ #1 __stage__new } \ace_reveal_tl
                           {#2}
                           {#3}    
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{stage}{ m }
        {
            \tl_if_eq:cNF { ace__reveal__ #1 __stage__new } \ace_reveal_tl
                          {\expandafter\comment}
        }
        {
            \tl_if_eq:cNF { ace__reveal__ #1 __stage__new } \ace_reveal_tl
                          {\expandafter\endcomment}
          }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

File in which I define the picture I'm using in which I implement stages:  this file is called **diagram.tex**

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-20,-13)(20,13)
    %..% compass directions %..% 
    {
        \psset{PointName=none,PointSymbol=none} 
        \pstGeonode(0,0){o}(1,0){r}(0,1){u}
        \pstRotation[RotAngle=20]{o}{r}[r1] 
        \pstGeonode(0,0){Q}
    }
    %% temporarily define midpont of segment(PQ) --> M to control positioning
    \pstGeonode[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none,PosAngle=0](0,0){tM}
    %% point outside the circle and the center of circle
    \pstTranslation[DistCoef=14,PosAngle=80]{o}{r1}{tM}[Q]
    \pstTranslation[DistCoef=10,PosAngle=-100]{r1}{o}{tM}[P]
    %% construct circle centered at P
    \pstCircleOA[Radius=\pstDistVal{9}]{P}{}

    %% construct mid-point between P and Q
    \pstTranslation[DistCoef=9,PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{o}{r}{P}[B]
    \pstTranslation[DistCoef=0.5,PointName=none,PointSymbol=none]{P}{Q}{P}[M]
    %% show constructions
    \begin{stage}{midpoint}
        \pstLineAB[linecolor=blue,linewidth=0.1pt,linestyle=dashed]{P}{Q}
        \pstGeonode[PointName=M,PosAngle=-90](M){showM}
    \end{stage}

    %% construct circle centered at M passing through P and Q
    \begin{stage}{large circle}
        \pstCircleOA[linecolor=blue,linewidth=0.2pt,linestyle=dashed]{M}{P}
    \end{stage}

    %% construct tangents
    \pstInterCC[PointName=none,PointSymbol=none,RadiusB=\pstDistVal{9}]{M}{P}{P}{}{U}{V}
    \begin{stage}{tangents}
        \testforstage{large circle}{
            \pstGeonode[PointName={U},PosAngle=-90](U){showU}
            \pstGeonode[PointName={V},PosAngle=110](V){showV}
        }{
            \pstGeonode[PointName={U},PosAngle=-50](U){showU}
            \pstGeonode[PointName={V},PosAngle=90](V){showV}
        }
        \pstLineAB[linecolor=red,nodesep=-8]{Q}{V}
        \pstLineAB[linecolor=red,nodesep=-8]{Q}{U}
    \end{stage}

\end{pspicture}
```

The main document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-eucl}
\psset{unit=0.15cm}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\input{stages}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

    \input{diagram} 

    \revealstage{midpoint}
    \input{diagram}

    \revealstage{large circle}
    \input{diagram}

    \revealstage{tangents}
    \input{diagram}

    \burystage{midpoint}
    \burystage{large circle}
    \input{diagram}

\end{document}
```

This creates:

[image]

> What's not working:

I would really like to be able to write something like the following lines in the *main document*:

```
\activatestage[reveal=midpoint,
               conceal={large circle,
                        midpoint}]
              {diagram}
```

But this above example is a bit more sophisticated than I've currently tried to implement.  Currently, I haven't written code to handle passing multiple values to be parse by the key.  I've only written something that I *believe* should be able to handle the following:

```
\activatestage[reveal=midpoint,
               conceal=large circle]
              {diagram}
```

And this is the code I use to try to implement this:

```
%% defining keys
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { stages }{
    reveal  .code:n = \fnc_reveal_stages:n #1,
    conceal .code:n = \fnc_conceal_stages:n #1
}

\cs_new:Npn \fnc_reveal_stages:n #1 {
        \tl_gset:cV { ace__reveal__ #1 __stage__new } \ace_reveal_tl
}

\cs_new:Npn \fnc_conceal_stages:n #1 {
        \tl_gset:cV { ace__reveal__ #1 __stage__new } \ace_conceal_tl
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\activatestage}{ o m }{
        \tl_set:Nn  \l__no_value_tl         { \NoValue    }
        \tl_set:Nn  \l__keys_present_tl     { #1 }
        \tl_show:N \l__keys_present_tl
        \bool_if:nF {        \tl_if_eq_p:NN \l__keys_present_tl  \l__no_value_tl) }
                {
                    \keys_set:nn{ stages }{#1}
                }
        \input{#2}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

I've put the above in its own file called **additions.tex**

Here's the main document where I try to implement the new approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-eucl}
\psset{unit=0.15cm}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\input{stages}
\input{additions}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

    \input{diagram} 

    \revealstage{midpoint}
    \input{diagram}

    \revealstage{large circle}
    \input{diagram}

    \revealstage{tangents}
    \input{diagram}

    \activatestage[reveal=midpoint,
                   conceal=large circle]
                  {diagram}

\end{document}
```

But this results in:

[image]

But this isn't doing what I expect (as you can see by comparing to my working example).  The key seems to only see the first letter of the value being passed to it.  How do I get the key to see the entire value?

Comment: At least it should be `reveal  .code:n = \fnc_reveal_stages:n {#1}` Always put braces around an `n`-type argument.

Comment: @egreg.  Oh how humiliating!  Such a simple mistake.  Thank you!

Comment: You should use a boolean, instead of comparing token lists for concealing or revealing the environment.

Comment: @egreg.  I'm not sure how to implement that.  The reason is that I would like the user to have the freedom to define the names for the blocks to be *revealed/concealed*.

Comment: You can define "named" conditionals with `\bool_new:c`, maybe checking first if they are already existent; then you can use `\bool_gset_true:c` and `\bool_gset_false:c` for setting them and `\bool_if:cTF` for using them.

Comment: @egreg.  OK.  I've now implemented something with booleans.  Very nice suggestion.  But then I do have a problem with `\bool_new:c`.  I wind up skipping using it because LaTeX complains about multiply defined commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enclose `n`-type arguments in braces: it should be

```
\keys_define:nn { stages }
 {
  reveal  .code:n = \fnc_reveal_stages:n  { #1 },
  conceal .code:n = \fnc_conceal_stages:n { #1 },
 }
```

---

Here's a proposal using booleans and a good deal of simplifications. However, you should also add a command for defining all allowed "stages".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-eucl}
\psset{unit=0.15cm}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

%% defining stages
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\revealstage}{ m }
 {
  \ace_reveal_stage:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ace_reveal_stage:n #1
 {
  \bool_if_exist:cF { g__ace_reveal_ #1 _stage_bool }
   { \bool_new:c { g__ace_reveal_ #1 _stage_bool } }
  \bool_gset_true:c { g__ace_reveal_ #1 _stage_bool }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\burystage}{ m }
 {
  \ace_conceal_stage:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ace_conceal_stage:n #1
 {
  \bool_if_exist:cF { g__ace_reveal_ #1 _stage_bool }
   { \bool_new:c { g__ace_reveal_ #1 _stage_bool } }
  \bool_gset_false:c { g__ace_reveal_ #1 _stage_bool }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\testforstage}{ m m m }
 {
  \bool_if:cTF { g__ace_reveal_ #1 _stage_bool } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{stage}{ m }
 {
  \bool_if:cF { g__ace_reveal_ #1 _stage_bool } {\comment}
 }
 {
  \bool_if:cF { g__ace_reveal_ #1 _stage_bool } {\endcomment}
 }

%%% Keyval syntax

\keys_define:nn { stages }{
    reveal  .code:n = \ace_reveal_stage:n  { #1 },
    conceal .code:n = \ace_conceal_stage:n { #1 },
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\activatestage}{ O{} m }
 {
  \keys_set:nn { stages } { #1 }
  \input{#2}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff  

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\activatestage[reveal=midpoint,
               conceal=large circle]
              {diagram}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Notes

1. Comparing token lists is not an efficient way; booleans are surely better.
2. Please, stick to the naming conventions; variables should start with `l_` or `g_` (or `l__` and `g__` if they are "internal").
3. `\keys_set:nn` is perfectly happy to process an empty argument, so

   ```
   \NewDocumentCommand{\activatestage}{ O{} m }
   ```

   is much more efficient than your testing of `\NoValue`. In any case, you should use `\IfNoValueTF` to test for the presence of an optional argument.

Comment: Other than the **accessor commands**, your MWE is pretty much exactly how I rewrote my document after your suggestion to use booleans.  Thank you for showing the `\bool_if_exist`.  I've also implemented setting multiple values through `\clist_set:Nn  \l__ace_stages {#1}` and then calling `\clist_map_inline:Nn  \l__ace_stage { \bool_gset_true:c { g__ace_reveal_ ##1 _stage_new } }`.  And *mutatis mutandis*, for the **conceal** side of things. I have some very nice code now.  Thank you again.